# ¿Como pasar mas de un método en ruta tipo resource Laravel?

Tags: php, funciones, laravel-8, routes

Tengo la siguiente ruta:

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
        Route::resource('actividad', App\Http\Controllers\RegisterActController::class)->names('admin.actividades');
    });
```

Estoy editando la función "show"  en el controlador:

```
 public function show($id)
{
     //
```

}

Requiero pasarle un nuevo parámetro a la ruta en este caso seria el id de la Orden de servicio ya que ocupo buscar todas las actividades relacionadas a esa orden, en mi vista index mando llamar a la ruta show:

```html
   

 @foreach ($actividad as $a)
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $a->id }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('admin.actividades.show', $a) }}">{{ $a->descripcion }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $a->serie }}{{ $a->folio }}</td>
        <td>{{ $a->fecha }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endforeach
```

```
Pensé en hacer algo así, pero no recibo por obvias razones el id de la orden de servicio

public function show($id, $a->osID){
          //
}
```

Investigando vi que podia modificar la ruta show para enviarle un nuevo parametro pero no encontre ejemplos que me sirvieran

Actualmente tengo asi mi funcion, solo que el query $act solo me trae una actividad porque el filtro "findOrFail" obtiene el $id de la actividad pero no tengo forma de obtener el id de la orden para filtrar por ese medio, por ello la modificación que quiero hacer en la ruta, espero me haya dado a entender

public function show($id)
{

```
       $act = actividad::join('os', 'os.id', '=', 'actividad.os_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'actividad.users_id')
            ->join('producto', 'producto.id', '=', 'actividad.producto_id')
            ->join('evidencia', 'evidencia.os_id', '=', 'os.id')
            ->select('url','actividad.id', 'producto.id AS productoID', 'os.id AS osID', 'users.name AS userName', 'users.ap1', 'users.ap2', 'actividad.fecha', 'actividad.cantidad', 'actividad.descripcion', 'actividad.users_id', 'actividad.producto_id', 'actividad.os_id', 'os.folioSerie', 'producto.codigo', 'producto.descripcionProd AS prodDesc')
            ->findOrFail($id);

        $b = evidencia::join('os', 'os.id', '=', 'evidencia.os_id')
            ->join('actividad', 'os.id', '=', 'actividad.os_id')
            ->select('url', 'evidencia.id')
            ->where('evidencia.os_id','=','actividad.OS_id')
            ->Orwhere('actividad.id','=', $id)
            ->get();
    
    return view('admin.actividades.show', ['b' => $b, 'act' => $act]);
    
    }
```

> Modelo tabla actividades:

```
    class actividad extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'actividad';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'fecha',
        'cantidad',
        'descripcion',
        'estatus',
        'users_id',
        'producto_id',
        'OS_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function producto(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\catProd');
    }

    public function orden(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ordenDS');
    }

    public function laboratorio(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\detLab');
    }

}
```

> Modelo tabla evidencia:

```
class evidencia extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'evidencia';

    protected $fillable = ['url','os_id'];
}
```

> Modelo tabla orden se servicio

```
    class ordenDS extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'os';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'folio',
        'serie',
        'folioSerie',
        'cliente_id',
        'contacto_id',
        'estatusOS'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías hacer un par de cosas,

Primero quitar el metodo show del resource, y armar uno personalizado de la siguiente forma;

```
Route::get('/actividad/{parametro-1/{parametro-2}}', [RegisterActController::class,'show'])->name('admin.actividades.mostrar');
Route::resource('actividad', RegisterActController::class)->name('admin.actividades')->except(['show',]);
```

Por otro lado, podes dejar tal cual las rutas, pero crear una relacion entre los modelos de Actividad y Evidencia (si no entendí mal) y con eso al tener una actividad, tambien ya tendrías todos los registros del modelo Evidencia asociados.

Si compartís el codigo de los modelos podemos ayudar un poco con esa parte.

Comment: Mil gracias por responder, hare las pruebas con la solución que me diste y regreso a actualizar la respuesta, ya compartí mis modelos, tengo evidencias relacionada a ordenes de servicio ya que según las reglas de negocio, una orden puede tener una o muchas actividades y una orden puede tener una o muchas evidencias.

Comment: Bueno, justamente, creo que podrías crear una relacion entre esos dos modelos, y con eso resolverias mas facilmente tu problemas, ya que podrias hacer por ejemplo $orden->evidencias y ahi ya recorrer todas las evidencias relacionadas